# failed: TypeError: expected string or buffer in robot framework (RIDE tool)

Tags: python, robotframework

Im trying to get the value of apples in the below JSON format. 
`{"fruit":{"apples":"bengaluru","oranges":"nagpur"}}`

But when ever i extract, i get the below error.
"failed: TypeError: expected string or buffer"

My keywords are below:

```
${json_object}=    Load JSON from file    C:\\Important documents\\JSON.json
${object}=    Create Dictionary    mango=Banaras
${json_object}=    Add Object To Json    ${json_object}    $..fruit    ${object}
${result}=    Get Json Value    ${json_object}    /fruit/apples
```

OR

```
${thedata}=    Evaluate    json.loads(${json_object})    json
```

I just need to get the value of apples as Bengaluru. (just the value).
Please help!

`pip list:
robotframework                          3.1.2
robotframework-extendedselenium2library 0.9.2
robotframework-httplibrary              0.4.2
robotframework-jsonlibrary              0.3.1
robotframework-mongodblibrary           0.3.4
robotframework-ride                     1.7.4
robotframework-selenium2library         1.8.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary          4.1.0
robotframework-stringformat             0.1.8`

Keyword driven in RIDE tool

Comment: Fruit in your json is have "S" but why in code no "S"?

Comment: sorry thats a mistake, my original json doesnot have "S", please ignore. i will edit

Comment: You don't post the exact error message, so we don't know where it happens. It would be better if you pasted a minimal reproducible example. I wan't to inform you that there is a new version of RIDE, 1.7.4.1.